Does Asterisk absolutely require Symmetric RTP from Twilio?
The question is as stated. I can't find a way to get 2-way audio working with Twilio and Asterisk (v.20.7); short of enabling their SymmetricRTP switch.  I suspect the problem is in the SDP handshake, but everything looks fine.
My setup is as follows.
Phone -- Twilio -- Firewall -- Asterisk -- Softphone(Twinkle)
Currently, if I switch on SymmetricRTP inside Twillio, then everything works perfectly fine.  But for reasons beyond the scope of the problem, I can not depend on a switch provided by Twilio to resolve a probable NAT issue.
This leaves me thinking that Asterisk is incorrectly, or isn't correctly, rewriting something when it negotiates the SDP connection between Twilio and itself through the firewall.  The firewall has a static IP and Domain associated with it which I've tried to point everything toward, but nothing seems to be working.
Without the symmetric-RTP switch, (Phone Initiated Call) I get 1-way audio (Softphone -> Phone).
Among the switches I've tried in the asterisk configs are:

external_media_address=mydomain.com
external_signaling_address=mydomain.com
rtp_symmetric=yes & no
force_rport=yes & no
rewrite_contact=yes & no

Current Configs look like:
pjsip.conf (excluding: auth and localuser components)
[transport-udp]
type=transport
protocol=udp
bind=0.0.0.0
local_net=192.168.64.0/22
external_media_address=mydomain.com
external_signaling_address=mydomain.com

[transport-tcp]
type=transport
protocol=tcp
bind=0.0.0.0
local_net=192.168.64.0/22
external_media_address=mydomain.com
external_signaling_address=mydomain.com

[twilio-trunk]
type=aor
contact=sip:mydomain.pstn.twilio.com

[twilio-trunk]
type=identify
endpoint=twilio-trunk
match=mydomain.pstn.twilio.com

[twilio-trunk]
type=endpoint
context=from-twilio
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
aors=twilio-trunk
outbound_auth=twilio-trunk-auth
from_domain=mydomain.pstn.twilio.com
rtp_symmetric=no
force_rport=no
rewrite_contact=no

rtp.conf
[general]
rtpstart=6000
rtpend=60000

Everything else is either default or unchanged.  Asterisk was installed onto an ubuntu 22.04 system from source.
